# What are some good models for stock price predictions?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, finance

For the fitting and forecasting of time-series data on stock price, the most frequent model I have heard of is ARIMA. ARIMA is actually conducting a regression of stock prices and residuals of stock prices in the few days prior to the current date. ARCH model and its derivatives model variances on the data in the previous few days.

However, for the stock price, in particular, I believe most traders will not only rely on the stock prices in the past few days but also on the general trends in the past few months or even years. Therefore, the behaviors of traders should not be modeled fully based on stock prices in the past few days.

Is there a well-established model that considers stock prices not only in the past few days but also on the overall trend? Or if not, is there a reason why modeling only on the stock prices in the past few days is better than modeling on earlier data?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about statistics as defined in the help center. Perhaps this would be suitable for quant.SE or economics.SE

Comment: Sorry I am new to this platform, but I thought I was asking about time-series forecasting.

Comment: Welcome! Since you're new, perhaps you'd find the [help] a useful place to start. The distinction that I'm making is that you're not asking a *statistical* question about time-series forecasting, but instead asking a domain-specific question about how to model stock prices over time. That is, the content of your question isn't about how a time-series model works in statistical terms, but instead is focused on how to do better at predicting the stock market in particular.

Comment: some would say [head and shoulders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_and_shoulders_(chart_pattern)) is a good model